# Openerp 7 : Query doesn't execute

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have this problem related to simple update query. I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

**The class and fields need to get updated**

```
class allowance_attendances(osv.osv):

    _name = "allowance.attendances"
    _description = "Allowance Attendances"
    _columns = { 

             'worked_hours':fields.datetime("Extra Hours"),
             'compati_hours' : fields.datetime("Compatible Hours"),
            }
```

**The update query I wrote**

```
cr.execute("""UPDATE allowance_attendances SET compati_hours = '%s',worked_hours='%s' WHERE att_date ='%s' and employee_id=%s"""%(comp_hours,cal_hours,cal_date,emp_id))
```

Data type of the **compati_hours** and **cal_hours** is **datetime.timedelta**

**Error massage is;**

```
2017-07-20 04:25:01,469 4170 ERROR testtest openerp.netsvc: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "6:59:00"
LINE 1: UPDATE allowance_attendances SET compati_hours = '6:59:00',w...
                                                         ^
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/audittrail/audittrail.py", line 532, in execute_cr
    return fct_src(cr, uid, model, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/hr_allowances/hr_allowances.py", line 482, in populate_attendance_normal_shift
    self.get_number_of_hours(cr, uid, ids, all_emp_id,all_date, all_sign_in, all_sign_out,all_sign_in2,all_sign_out2, all_emp_type, context)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/hr_allowances/hr_allowances.py", line 336, in get_number_of_hours
    cr.execute("""UPDATE allowance_attendances SET compati_hours = '%s',worked_hours='%s' WHERE att_date ='%s' and employee_id=%s"""%(comp_hours,cal_hours,cal_date,emp_id))
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manisha/HR_Workspace/openerp-7.0/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "6:59:00"
LINE 1: UPDATE allowance_attendances SET compati_hours = '6:59:00',w...
                                                         ^

2017-07-20 04:25:01,470 4170 INFO testtest werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017 04:25:01] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/allowance.attendances:populate_attendance_normal_shift HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: if `compati_hours` is a `datetime` field shouldn't your data be a `datetime` instead of only `time`

Comment: No even I tried this with converting to string and tried to store it in char field it doesn't store either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no field only Time. If you want to store only Time. You may use `fields.char`

**Date**

Store date. The field provides some helpers:

- context_today returns current day date string based on tz
- today returns current system date string
- from_string returns datetime.date() from string
- to_string returns date string from datetime.date

```py
>>> from openerp import fields

>>> adate = fields.Date()
>>> fields.Date.today()

'2014-06-15'

>>> fields.Date.context_today(self)

'2014-06-15'

>>> fields.Date.context_today(self, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())

'2014-06-15'

>>> fields.Date.from_string(fields.Date.today())

datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 19, 32, 17)

>>> fields.Date.to_string(datetime.datetime.today())

'2014-06-15'
```

**DateTime**

Store datetime. The field provide some helper:

- context_timestamp returns current day date string based on tz
- now returns current system date string
- from_string returns datetime.date() from string
- to_string returns date string from datetime.date

```py
>>> fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())

datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 21, 26, 1, 248354, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Brussels' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

>>> fields.Datetime.now()

'2014-06-15 19:26:13'

>>> fields.Datetime.from_string(fields.Datetime.now())

datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 19, 32, 17)

>>> fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now())

'2014-06-15 19:26:13''2014-06-15 19:26:13'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for nice clarification. I stored it as a char since I needed that value on front-end. Thank you so much